# Compiling SubSonic 3.0.0.4 from sources

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I downloaded SubSonic 3.0.0.4 sources from https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0 and compiled it using Visual Studio 2010. When I add the compiled SubSonic.Core.dll to my own project and try to use the SimpleRepository like this

```
SimpleRepository repo = new SimpleRepository(ProviderFactory.GetProvider(connectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient"), SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);
```

the dll crashes:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in SubSonic.Core.dll

Additional information: The type initializer for 'SubSonic.DataProviders.DynamicProxyInterceptionStrategy' threw an exception.
```

Crash occurs at SubSonic's DbDataProvider.cs on line 56:

```
InterceptionStrategy = new DynamicProxyInterceptionStrategy(this);
```

All works fine if I download ready-made SubSonic.Core.dll from the project's web site and use it. But I wanted to compile it myself, because I'll try to do some modifications on it later.

Thanks
Bapu

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with downloading the latest revision from Git and upgrading Subsonic in an existing project (which has a Microsoft SQL database). I first compiled the Subsonic.Core project, swapped my old dll with the new and had the same error as you.

The inner exception states that it's missing a reference to Castle.Core. Just add a reference to Caste.Core with is found in the /lib folder and you should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Adding the Castle.Core.dll, solved the same issue for me.